# Array Reactivity Issues

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having issues with array reactivity, please see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/jk1kadxq/

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
        grid: {
        rows: [{}]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow: function () {
        this.grid.rows.push({});
    },
    setRow: function (row) {
        console.log(row);
        this.$set(row, 'cell', 'Test');
    }
  },
  watch: {
    'grid.rows': {
      deep: true,
      handler: function (rows, oldRows) {
        console.log('Rows updated', rows, oldRows);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="row in grid.rows">
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.cell"></td>
      <td><button type="button" @click="setRow(row)">Set</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" @click="addRow">Add</button>
</div>
```

1. If a row has not been edited manually, clicking "Set" button sets the field to "Test" and all the further updates to it are catched in watcher.
2. If a row has been edited manually first, watcher is not triggered, and clicking "Set" button does not immediately update the field. Adding another row updates the current row.

Is there a different way to add new array members? This page says it's ok to just add: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue... All the properties of objects should be initialized.

So in my case, the proper way to add a row is: `this.grid.rows.push({cell: ''});`

It would be nice though to initialize object properties when binding to controls, if not initialized yet.